# Mocking a private method in an Expectations block causes "IllegalStateException: Missing invocation to mocked type at this point"

Tags: jmockit

I have a JUnit test that uses a JMockit `Expectations` block:

```
@Tested
private MyTestedClass myTestedClass;

@Injectable
private MyOtherClass myOtherClass;

@Test
public void publicBooleanMethodTest() {

    new Expectations() {{
        invoke(myOtherClass, "privateMethod");
        result = true;
    }};

    myTestedClass.run(); // Calls myOtherClass.privateMethod();
}
```

However, this results in the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing invocation to mocked type at this point; please make sure such invocations appear only after the declaration of a suitable mock field or parameter

As you can see, `myClass` is mocked via `@Injectable`, so I'm not sure why the error is happening. I have also found that if I change the scope of `privateMethod()` to public, everything works.

What is going on and how can I fix this? It worked fine in JMockit 1.22, but now fails in JMockit 1.23 and greater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMockit 1.23 removed support for mocking private methods in `Expectations` blocks. From the [release notes](http://jmockit.org/changes.html):

> ### Version 1.23 (Apr 24, 2016):
>
> - **Dropped** support for the mocking of private methods/constructors when using the Expectations API, to prevent misuse. If still needed, they can be mocked or stubbed out with the application of a `MockUp<T>`.

<s>Unfortunately, the erroneous error message is currently seen as "too costly too fix" [by the development team](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/321#issuecomment-240248491).</s> A better error message was added in JMockit 1.28 as a result of this discussion.

The error log says to use `MockUp<T>` as an alternative. In this case, the code would be as follows:

```
@Tested
private MyTestedClass myTestedClass;

@Injectable
private MyOtherClass myOtherClass;

@Test
public void publicBooleanMethodTest() {
    // Partially mock myOtherClass
    new MockUp<MyOtherClass>(myOtherClass) {
        @Mock boolean privateBooleanMethod() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    myTestedClass.run(); // Calls myOtherClass.privateMethod();
}
```

Comment: I can probably change the `Deencapsulation.invoke` methods so they throw a better exception when called from inside an expectation block; will look into it. The more important point to note here is to *not mock private methods*; there is no valid reason to do it (until proven otherwise by someone willing to show a realistic example test - but I wouldn't bet on it).

Comment: @Rogério A better exception for `Deencapsulation.invoke` would be greatly appreciated! A lot of time was wasted trying to figure out what the error message meant. We have several unit tests that rely on mocking private methods for what we feel are legitimate reasons. What would be the best way to show you an example test?

Comment: Post it in a new issue in the github issue tracker; or in the JMockit users group.

Comment: @Rogério how about just to verify that path was or was not executed?